# laravel 6 - multi-tenant based CSS

Tags: css, laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-6

I have a multi-tenant system but I don't know how to go about setting css based on the current tenant. The tenant can either be a sub-domain or be set once a user logs in. but how would I go about setting up the css for this?

Tenant styles such as primary colour, secondary colour are saved in a table `tenant_styles`. I have created the model for this and set the following in the **Styles** Model:

```
public function tenant() {
     return $this->belongsTo(Tenant::class);
}
```

and in the **Tenant** Model:

```
public function styles() {
     return $this->hasOne(Styles::class);
}
```

I can get the tenant styles using `$tenant->styles`

I'm not sure on how to set up the css stylesheet so that I can use the tenant styles. I need it so that if the tenant is the subdomain, the css is set on the login page.
but then if the tenant is not a subdomain, use the default colours and then once the user has logged in set the tenant colours.

Comment: If the css is static, just make some sheets and then load them based on a condition. (`<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ $user->type == 1 ? 'light-theme.css' : 'dark-theme.css' }}">`)

Comment: Too broad a question, I'd start with middleware to detect the subdomain and drop the `Tenant` object into the session. During login you can also populate that session variable if needed. Use it to show your styles as desired.

Comment: hi, thanks for replying @miken32, @IGP. The colours can be anything so loading them based on a condition is not an option. The issue i'm having is i don't know how to generate the css so that it can have dynamic colours. i know i can just use something like a `<Style> .primary-colour { color: $styles->primary-colour; }</style>` in the head section but I don't think this is very practical if I have a lot of css styles.

Comment: Use a Sass stylesheet that’s recompiled as needed. Save it in local storage.

Comment: I've created a blade.php file that will have access to the tenant styles variable. Do you think it's better to create a route to the stylesheet and then include it in the head like `<link type="text/css" href="/css/styles" rel="stylesheet">` or better to use `@include('layout.styles')`?